# getReference undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, modal

I ran into a problem that just doesn't make sense. I am dynamically creating component (modal) and passing attributes into it.

this is the method that takes care of that:

```
showModal: function (component, event, helper) {

    var objectFieldsNew = component.get('v.objectFields');
    console.log('MAP GET' , component.get('v.objectFields'));
    console.log('MAP GETREFERENCE' , component.getReference('v.objectFields'));

    if (component.get('v.editMode') === true) {
        objectFieldsNew.objectFieldToTargetTypeMap = helper.objectToMap(objectFieldsNew.objectFieldToTargetTypeMap);
    }


    var fieldMapping = component.getReference('v.fieldMappingDto');
    console.log('objectFields before the component creation', objectFieldsNew)
    console.log('fieldMapping component creation', fieldMapping.sfFieldAPIName);
    var modalBody;
    console.log('OBJECT FIELDS', objectFieldsNew);
    console.log('OBJECT FIELDS list', objectFieldsNew.accessibleObjectFields);
    $A.createComponents([
            ["c:relatedRecords", {
                "fieldMappingDto": fieldMapping, 'objectFields': objectFieldsNew,
                "nextRef": objectFieldsNew.objectFieldToTargetTypeMap.get(fieldMapping.sfFieldAPIName)
            }],

        ],
        function (components, status) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                modalBody = components[0];

                component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                    header: "Application Confirmation",
                    body: modalBody,

                    showCloseButton: true,
                    cssClass: "my-modal,my-custom-class,my-other-class",

                })
            }
        }
    );
},
```

So my question is: why object objectFields is null when I when i get reference of it, but is not null when I just pass the actual object copy?

here goes log from the console:
    [image]

Comment: Please make your question more clear: when is it null and when it is not (on which line of code and in what event / situation) ?

Comment: @ItaiShmida
Well I re-wrote the code, and the question in not relevant for me anymore, but here it goes: Why console.log(getReference) prints out empty object, however console.log(get) applied to the same object prints out object structure?